# PHP extract proper array from within text string

Tags: php, arrays, pel

I have a text string that looks like this

```
$string = "abcdefgh Value : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 44 [1] => 332 ) ) Text : ijklmn";
```

I want to pull out the array text as a proper PHP array. How can I best do this? I experimented with `substr()`, but I could not get it to work.

The reason for this is because I'm using the below which outputs various arrays among all sorts of text.

```
$jpeg = new PelJpeg($filename);
$exif = $jpeg->getExif();
echo $exif;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you even put it into a string?

Comment: Are you sure it is a string or are you debugging and this is the value of a variable?

Comment: Instead of straight `echo`, you might first `json_encode()` it. That'll make things way more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing, you may need to do more work to get the Exif data. For example:

```
$jpeg = new PelJpeg($filename);
$exif = $jpeg->getExif();
```

> The Exif data is not stored directly in this object, instead it is stored in a PelTiff object, which can be retrieved using the getTiff() method:

```
$tiff = $exif->getTiff();
$ifd0 = $tiff->getIfd(); 
$desc = $ifd0->getEntry(PelTag::IMAGE_DESCRIPTION); 
echo 'The description: ' . $desc->getValue();
```

Reference: [Using PEL in applications](http://lsolesen.github.io/pel/doc/PEL/tutorial_using.pkg.html)

Comment: @user2029890 Were you able extract the exif data?